# How show a string like this 00019 in csv

Tags: java, csv

I put in my csv some results Like this:

```
ID            COUNTRY
0009             FR
0006             FR
```

The problem is that when I open my file.CSV,I read under ID the values 9 and 6 and not 0009 and 0006. How is it possibile and How I can avoid this problem?  Anyone can help me?

Comment: are you reading those as String?

Comment: Yes I read the ID from a string

Comment: Show us your code at least. Perhaps you're parsing to int instead of string.

Comment: I mean abount "leading zeros" in a string that I put in my file.csv. I want that the zero aren't delete because when I open my file.csv the zero are delete

Comment: Are you opening in excel?

Comment: Show us the code already!  How can we answer without seeing how you're reading it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Given that the question is tagged with Java.)

If you have a CSV as mentioned, which is tab separated:

```
ID      COUNTRY
0009    FR
0006    FR
```

Suppose it is located at: `src/com/stackoverflow/myfile.csv`

You can read it as below:

```java
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CsvReader {

    public static final String CSVFILE = "src/com/stackoverflow/myfile.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\\t+"; // use tab as separator

        try {    
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSVFILE));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] info = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();
                details.append("ID = ");
                details.append(info[0]);
                details.append(", Country = ");
                details.append(info[1]);

                System.out.println(details.toString());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the output would be:

```
ID = ID, Country = COUNTRY
ID = 0009, Country = FR
ID = 0006, Country = FR
```

Note: it is 0009 and 0006

**UPDATED (Just Java 8 way to read the CSV file):**

```java
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CsvReader {

    public static final String CSVFILE = "src/com/stackoverflow/myfile.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cvsSplitBy = "\\t+"; // use tab as separator

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(CSVFILE))) {

            stream.forEach(line -> {
                String[] info = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();
                details.append("ID = ");
                details.append(info[0]);
                details.append(", Country = ");
                details.append(info[1]);

                System.out.println(details.toString());
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could escape the value as a string

```
ID            COUNTRY 
"0009"             FR 
"0006"             FR
```

I believe your problem has nothing to do with Java, I'd assume you're using a tab processor (Excel, Calc, ...). When opening the file, you have to explicitly set the column type to text, otherwise it will "guess" it's a number and clean the leading zeros.

Comment: I use libre office, but when I open the file.csv I read the number just wrong also if before to put values in file a read id and the result is correct but when I open file.csv is wrong

Comment: @Poppy: open the file with notepad, Notepad++ and you will see what is really in the file. If it's wrongly written (by Java code), without posting your Java code nobody will give you any reasonable answer